# Show Dropdown value in listing search instead of dropdown key using builder plugin

Tags: octobercms

I am using OctoberCMS and using one of its awesome plugins called as [builder](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder) and so far so good.

But, I am stuck at one stage and confused how to achieve this. This is my scenario below.

I have created one new field called as "status" in my one of the plugins in which I have key values like `(0=>Inactive, 1=>Active)` .. this works fine as i am able to insert or update values based on my status selection..

But the thing is, when i go to listing page, i have selected a "status" field but its showing me values 0 or 1 instead of Active or Inactive.

How can i show Active or Inactive instead of 0 and 1 using builder plugin or any other way.. I need to be able to search and sort as well ..

Can anyone guide me for the same ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can define a custom SQL select statement to use for the value.

In your case,

```
mistake_status:
        label: Status
        searchable: true     
        select: CASE WHEN (status =  '1' ) THEN 'Active' ELSE 'In Active' END // you can pass any custom  SQL statement.
```

It will also helpful in search functionality of grid.