# How to display 'Inactive/Active' for switch type in OctoberCMS list?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I tried under `format` using this YAML syntax with `Switch` type or `Text` type

```
format: !e '%s == 0 ? Active : Inactive'
```

But doesn't work as expected. Is there anyway without modifying the controllers? How to display the word 'Inactive/Active' instead of 'Yes/No'?

Comment: You can use `select` - `select: CASE WHEN (status =  '1' ) THEN 'Active' ELSE 'In Active' END // you can pass any custom  SQL statement.` .. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799476/show-dropdown-value-in-listing-search-instead-of-dropdown-key-using-builder-plug/40801854 .. Upvote that question/ answer if you find that useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

First, create a partial for example `_active_column.htm` whit this content (as example):

```
<?php if($value){ ?>
    Active
<?php }else{ ?>
    Inactive
<?php } ?>
```

Then, in `columns.yaml`, you can invoke partial like this:

```
active:
    label   : Active
    type    : partial
    path    : ~/plugins/your/plugin/models/your_model/_active_column.htm
```

In this example, `$value` takes value of `active` column from Model.

Comment: There is a another way as well to achieve this..  see what I have done here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799476/show-dropdown-value-in-listing-search-instead-of-dropdown-key-using-builder-plug No need to create `partial`.. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#field-switch), you can write this on `fields.yaml` file:

```
boolean_column:
    label: Boolean option
    type: switch
    comment: Comment of this
    on: Active
    off: Inactive
```

Comment: `fields.yaml` only works for form configuration. There is a separate configuration for  list which is `columns.yaml`. But that option doesn't work for list. I tried it just now and it still shows 'Yes/No'

Comment: Ok, in this cases I use partial, let me search for an example.